# Ubuntu 23.10 - small fonts not rendered properly

Tags: ubuntu, fonts

After upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10 i've discovered that some websites became almoast unreadable.

Any ideas what to do to fix this ?
[Tahoma 'font'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GBN9.png)

I've pinpointed the problem to not properly rendered small size of Tahoma font, screenshot attached.

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.2/+bug/412195

Removing `fonts-wine` solves the problem.

This problem has reappeared after 13 years...

Comment: My eyeballs thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue but deleting fonts-wine is not good solution for me.

so i found solution here :
https://gist.github.com/maxwelleite/913b6775e4e408daa904566eb375b090

just print:

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/maxwelleite/913b6775e4e408daa904566eb375b090/raw/ttf-ms-tahoma-installer.sh -q -O - | sudo bash
```

***WARNING**. This above command downloads a script from the web and **executes it as root**. This is a potential vulnerability as **malicious code could be injected**. Better download the file, check it, and execute it manually.*